# Showing holomorphic function is constant via conformal map

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show that if $f: \mathbb{C} \to U$ where $U = \{ z\in \mathbb{C} : x \notin [0,1] \}$ then $f$ is constant.

My idea is to map $U$ bijectively onto a bounded region, however I am struggling to find the suitable conformal maps! I'm guessing something that is only defined on the cut plane with $[0,1]$ removed, maybe $\sqrt{z^2 -1}$?

Thanks for any help

Comment: $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ would be defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$. Of course it is easy to map $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$ conformally to $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$. Or take a Möbius transformation mapping $[0,1]$ to $(-\infty,0] \cup \{\infty\}$, or ...

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is right and you are almost done. Hint: where does $z\mapsto z+\frac1z$ map the pointed disk $\mathbb D-\{0\}$ to?

Comment: This should be straightforward but I'm actually struggling to see where that map sends the unit disc. Do you have any hints to find this? Normally it seems describing the region in a sensible way i.e $|z| \le 1$ works, but I can't use that here

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform

Comment: I haven't come across those maps before, thanks for the link